# Angular 8 - Globalize is not defined after ng build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, javascript-globalize

I am using Angular CLI 8.1.1 and JqWidgets 8.* 
When serve the application using `ng serve` everything works fine.
Although when run with ng build I get an error `Globalize is not defined` 
Can someone help me understand why this might be happening?

I have tried downgrading Angular to 8.0.6

Comment: Try `import * as Globalize from 'globalize';` This may work.

Comment: @BuwanekaDeSilva No worries, it was a bug on JqWidgets side which they resolved in their new version. Thanks though :)